# Display nested JSON data on Angular Material Table

Tags: json, angular, datatables, nested, angular-material

The Json file has following format -

```
{
"products": {

    "items":[
      {
        "productId": "1",
        "dept": "home",
        "itemtype": "small"
      },
      {
       "productId": "2",
        "dept": "kitchen",
        "itemtype": "medium"
      }
       ] }}
```

This is suppose to display on a material table, I can see the data has passed as shows in the console, but not visible in the material table.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" >
<ng-container matColumnDef="productId" >
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element ">{{element.productId}}  
   </td>
 </ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="dept" >
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> department</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element ">{{element.dept}}  
   </td>
 </ng-container>
 <ng-container matColumnDef="itemtype" >
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Item type</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element ">{{element.itemtype}}  
   </td>
 </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
 <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the `JSON` into a variable like,

```
const jsonData = {
"products": {
    "items":[
      {
        "productId": "1",
        "dept": "home",
        "itemtype": "small"
      },
      {
       "productId": "2",
        "dept": "kitchen",
        "itemtype": "medium"
      }
    ] 
  }
}
```

Then the `datasource` needs to be declared with array `items` like,

```
dataSource = jsonData.products.items;
```

And sisplay columns with properties like,

```
  displayedColumns = ['productId', 'dept', 'itemtype'];
```

And `HTML` template refering these properties,

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="productId">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.productId}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="dept">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> department </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.dept}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="itemtype">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Item type </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.itemtype}} </td>
  </ng-container>


  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

> [**Working material table Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v8hfwh)

Comment: I have the json file saved locally, hence as I have mentioned.  So does it needs to be updated with const jsonData ? Sorry but I am totally new and lost. help please.

Comment: My project has a json file saved locally under the assets folder, just to confirm.

Comment: @Sz2013, Here you go https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-aucg8w .. I have stored the json inside assets folder as ```config.json``` then used service as ```config.service.ts``` and called the json through http then subscribed in ```app.component.ts``` then retrieve the data and store it to ```dataSource``` ..

Comment: thanks a lot. Just a question , it seems it is not getting 'product'  properly as says 'Property 'products' does not exist on type 'Object'.'  Also I didn't quite understand the use of Hello ts.

Comment: @Sz2013, You can replace the ```data.products.items``` with ```data['products'].items``` and also please ignore all other files except ```app component and module``` The exact code actually lies in this app only ..

Comment: @Sz2013, Please look into this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-8huoyi for more clarity..

Comment: Thanks a lot , it works. Have another question, I am trying to use Material Table filter, but the table type can't be assigned to [ ]  . Any suggestions will be really helpful.

Comment: @Sz2013, I have not used filter but you can take a look at this https://stackblitz.com/angular/beggoegpvmk and compare with your code and you can analyse what changes needs to be done.. But I believe I have provided for the things you asked in question, If so feel free to accept the solution..

Answer (score 0):

The `dataSource` must be an array (in your case is `products['items']`).